# How can I publish from a Facebook fanpage to a fan's wall?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to repopoduce this type of dialog (and post a status update to the user profile) on a Facebook fan page? 
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Feed_Forms

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to write an app for or add an app to your page that allows this functionality. I'm not aware of any other way to do it.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't find any fanpage solution either.